# Analytical solution to a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I have an equation of the form:

$$(A+x)(B\cos(x) - C\sin(x)) - D = 0$$

where $A,B,C,D$ are constants. I am solving this numerically now for a real time software which is slowing everything down. Is it possible to have an analytical solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just the special case $x\sin(x) = 1$, which is to say $A = 0, B = 0, C = -1, D = 1$ is, as far as I know, impossible. At least [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*sin(x)+%3D+1) can't do it. That being said, note that you can simplify away the $B$, since $B\cos(x) - C\sin(x) = C'\sin(x + \phi)$ for some $C'$ and $\phi$, at which point you can do a substitution $y = x+\phi$ which gives you $(A+\phi + y)\cdot C'\sin(y) - D = 0$.

Comment: You could use $acosx+ bsinx=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}sin(x+c)$ and  the graphic to have ideas about the solutions positions.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam : Standard usage is $a\cos x + b\sin x = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin(x+c)$, not $a cos x + b sin x = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} sin(x+c).$ Use backslashes in \sin and \cos. $$\text{Right: } a\cos x + b\sin x = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin(x+c)$$ $$\text{Wrong: } a cos x + b sin x = \sqrt{a^2+b^2} sin(x+c)$$